# Replacing html text with parameters in url?

Tags: url, parameters, replace

I have the url parmeters http://www.nositeinparticular.coom/product1**?test=brand&old=Superman&new=Batman.**

I was wanting to know the proper way to use javascript to do the following;

Look to see if test=brand
If it does replace all the values of old with the value of new, ie replacing the word Superman with Batman.

I have this so far to see if test equals brand:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = location.pathname;

    if (url.indexOf("test=brand")) {

    }
```

How would I go about parsing the values from the url and running the replacment?

Comment: Look here for how to parse the query string: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2880929/1402923

Comment: Thanks.  I guess my syntax was a bit off.  Appriciate it!